# Flutter: Get Wrong days of the week

Tags: flutter, days, weekday, intl, flutter-intl

from Monday - Thursday, I get the right days, but from Friday, I get the wrong days. Why?

Code example:

```
Text(DateFormat('EEEE').format(DateTime(DateTime.friday))),
```

And i get Saturday. Is that a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug, `DateTime()` default constructor takes `year` as the first argument:

```
  DateTime(int year,
      [int month = 1,
      int day = 1,
      int hour = 0,
      int minute = 0,
      int second = 0,
      int millisecond = 0,
      int microsecond = 0])
      : this._internal(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond,
            microsecond, false);
```

So this code:

```
DateTime date = DateTime(DateTime.friday);
```

Is essentially constructing a `DateTime` of the year 5, because `DateTime.friday` is nothing more than a `const int` that equals to 5:

```
  static const int monday = 1;
  static const int tuesday = 2;
  static const int wednesday = 3;
  static const int thursday = 4;
  static const int friday = 5;
  static const int saturday = 6;
  static const int sunday = 7;
  static const int daysPerWeek = 7;
```

Formatting with `DateFormat` returns Saturday which happens to be the first day of the year:

```
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

main() {
  DateTime date = DateTime(DateTime.friday); // creates a DateTime of the year 5
  print(date.year);    // year: 5
  print(date.month);   // month: Jan (default = 1)
  print(date.weekday); // day: Saturday (first day of the year)
  print("${date.year}-${date.month}-${date.day}"); // 5-1-1
}
```

**`DateTime` should be used to define a specific *Date and Time*, for example, Friday 11th Dec 2020, it can't be used to define *any* Friday.**